How does modular arithmetic work in quirk?
From the "How to use Quirk" document, the equation for the $+A$ function is given by $|A⟩|E⟩ \mapsto |A⟩|E+A \; (\text{mod} \;2^{\text{len}(E)})⟩$. However, I am specifically interested in the $+A \; (\text{mod} \; R)$ and $\times A \;(\text{mod} \; R)$ functions. For example, I understand that this circuit which adds $+1$ to the least significant qubit but does not allow carry-over. However, if I resize the $+A \; (\text{mod} \; R)$ function to act on the two least significant qubits I get this circuit, which has the same results for the first two rows of the amplitude display, but the following two rows are left unaffected. Similarly, if I expand the addition to the 3 least significant qubits I get this circuit, which once again adds 1 to the first two rows, but now does nothing to the following 6 rows.
My question is, what is the explicit equation used here? There is clearly a $+A \; (\text{mod} \; R)$ operation being implemented, but it somehow depends upon how many qubits that function is acting on.

The function being implemented is:
if x < R:
    x += A
    x %= R

more formally:
$$\sum_x \alpha_x |x\rangle \rightarrow \sum_x \alpha_x \Big|(x + (x < R) \cdot A) \bmod R\Big\rangle$$
The reason increasing the size of the "+A (mod R)" box is making fewer states change is that more values of x can be represented by larger registers, and the x < R condition filters out all those additional values.

This is really helpful. There is just one more thing that I am confused by. Using your notation with my example decimal $0 \mapsto 1$, which makes perfect sense, but decimal $17 \mapsto 18$. In this case $x>R$ so it appears that nothing should happen.

@thespaceman Because you have a two bit register, the bits of 17 are decomposed into the part covered by the register and the part that isn't. Within the part that is the bits are 01 = 1 in decimal, which is less the the modulus of 3, and so those two bits get incremented mod 3.
